# How small a punched card or punched tape batch job could be?

Tags: ibm, punched-cards, besm-6

A while ago I read [a post](https://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) about creating the smallest possible ELF executable doing something observable — printing the number 42, for example — which Linux could accept and execute successfuly. The result was *45 bytes*.

This prompts a question: among retro systems which accepted batch jobs on punched cards or punched tape, has any of them had the job control language concise enough to allow a complete job on a single punched card, or its equivalent?

I have a vague recollection reading that the trick has been pioneered on IBM 1401, and such jobs were called "koans", but I was not able to find a concrete example.
It would be interesting to see if the contents of the card included at least some meta-information for an operating system to parse, or just the bare machine commands for a boot loader.

**How does an IBM 1401 koan look like, and were there other systems which allowed "koans"?**

---

For an example from the other side of the Iron Curtain, a minimalistic BESM-6 batch job, using a streamed format with explicit line breaks, printing "HELLO WORLD" would look like

```
ШИФР 123400^ОЗУ 1^ВРЕ 1^ВХО 1^ЕВ1K000640003K000740000C0000000500000006C0070000040000000БHELLO Б WORLDЕКОНЕЦ
```

translated, that is

```
USER 123400^RAM 1^TIM 1^STA 1^ЕS1I000640003I000740000D0000000500000006D0070000040000000THELLO T WORLDЕFINIS
```

which would fit on a punched card in the compact (byte-based) encoding, one of the encodings accepted by the OS, that allows 120 characters per card.

Legend:

- `USER`: 4 digits of user ID, two digits for the job ID (arbitrary)
- `RAM`: requested number of pages (1 page = 6 Kb) of RAM
- `TIM`: requested time in seconds (1)
- `STA`: start address (1)
- `E` - end of resource section
- `S1` - start loading at address 1
- `I000640003` - instruction @1: "print" syscall, control words start at address 3
- `I000740000` - instruction @2: "terminate" syscall
- `D0000000500000006` - data @3: start (5) and end (6) address for printing, inclusive
- `D0070000040000000` - data @4: one of the 0s - text format; 70 octal - start position 56, roughly centered on a line; 4 - flag "last control word".
- `THELLO`  and `T WORLD` - data @5 and @6: text information, 6 characters per word.
- `E` - end of segment introduced by `S1`
- `FINIS` - end of job (the Russian word for "end" is 5 letters long)

Comment: The IBM 1620 bootloader for any load-and-go program was a single card.  It was left sitting on the card reader and you'd stick it on the front of your deck.  Don't know if this bootloader thing counts.  You could fit 6 instructions (possibly 7?) on a single card.  Possibly there were single card utilities - like print card deck to line console typewriter ... don't remember ...

Comment: Well, Not sure about JCL batch jobs as I would expect the m  to need several cards, but a binary loader job could do useful stuff on a /360. A colleague of mine who did do service since the early 1970s had a useful test job for disk maintenance on a single card. It wold neet to be booted from in turn to select a disk drive and do a certain search pattern which could be used to adjust the head movement by just listening to it.

Comment: @davidbak If the "load and go" card would not anything interesting *by itself*, it does not count.

Comment: @Raffzahn "Booted from" I can believe. If 80 to 120 bytes of binary on a punched tape could do quite a lot, then a capability to boot from punched cards would definitely provide for a similar functionality. I wonder if a user job submitted to an OS could be that short.

Comment: @LeoB. But that means that there is for one an OS, and more important that OS is already booted.  Also, that makes it arbitrary, as what a job is and what an OS is a rather blurry thing on a mainframe as applications quite often were loaded directly, being their own OS. /360 can boot (or better load, as it was called back then) from all devices that are attached to a channel. No matter if Disk, tape, punch card or whatsoever. When the load button was hit, the IOC will simply load the first block from the device selected and execute whatever is delivered.

Comment: @Raffzahn Indeed, that's exactly what the words "batch job" in the title imply. A batch job is something that can be queued within the computer if some requested resources are not available, then selected for execution and finished without user interaction. Surely there must have been operating systems allowing to submit such batch jobs on punched tape (in a compact form, presumably, rather than in fixed-size records of 80 chars to mimic punched cards); were there?

Comment: @LeoB. - well, it made the whole thing _go_.  For some points-of-view, that's pretty interesting!  But I understand your position.

Comment: Does the material to be executed have to be on the card?  If not, it might be possible to drop a single [RUNJOB](https://icl1900.co.uk/g3/runjob.html) command in a GEORGE card reader ('NO USER context' means not logged in).  But maybe you still need an EOF card after it.

Comment: @LeoB. Not really. The concept of batch job you present implies the existence of an operating system offering storage units to hold spool a job (queuing) and resource management.But batch jobs are more simple than that. They do not need any OS. Only a card reader holing a stack of cards that gets startet. It has already been that way before computers and earliest machines started out exactly that way. Also, not I said 'any device' which as well include punch tapes - except, they were a really rare sight on /360. /360 are data processing. And they are block orientated.

Comment: @Raffzahn That part of the question can be left out for now.  Any concrete example of a 1401 (or a later machine) demo koan showing what they could do on one punched card, be it printing the older equivalent of "Hello world", or blinking some front panel lights, or something of that sort, that is fully self-contained (rather that reading from some disk and jumping there), will be good.

Comment: @LeoB. but that's exactly the point. Its possible to fit a /360 program on a single punch card to print a line, produce console output or punch another card when loaded via IPL.